# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'decision_function_shape'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I tried creating a **SVM Classifier**, as:

```
# Create a SVM Classifier
model = SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
            decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='linear',
            max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
            tol=0.001, verbose=False
            )
```

**(Using Python 2.7)**

But getting this error--

> TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument
>   'decision_function_shape'

Any thoughts on that will be very useful. Cheers!

Comment: You could simply leave it out because you're using `None`, which is the default

Comment: Which version of `sklearn` do you have installed? It looks like the `decision_function_shape` argument was only added in versions 0.17+. for example here's the documentation from 0.16 [which lacks that argument](http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html).

Comment: It's 0.16.1. I tried to install the update but it's kept on saying- No matching distribution found for the upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did upgrade my `sklearn` to `version 0.18`. Earlier it was `0.16.1` and as @coryKramer suggested-- **decision_function_shape argument was only added in versions 0.17+.**

So I followed his suggestion and upgraded and now everything is working just fine.

Meanwhile, here's **how to upgrade from cmd in Windows, using pip**.

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.18 --force-reinstall
```